# Silverlight drag n drop element hides when outside of ListBox

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, listbox, z-index

I implemented a drag and drop of an image from a Grid to another Grid using built-in MouseDragElementBehavior class. Then I needed to use a bit more complex layout for the source items so used ListBox and ItemTemplate instead.

The problem is now when dragging an item from the ListBox it is only visible when above the ListBox. How do I make it always visible and following mouse cursor anywhere while being dragged?

Comment: There is no "built-in" `MouseDragElementBehavior` it isn't even found in the Silverlight SDK, it is actually in the Blend SDK.

Comment: It's in the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly. Sorry I didn't know which SDK it was in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of writing your own implementation using the Blend SDK, that you use the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) `ListBoxDragDropTarget` control.

The reason the item disappears in your element is that the `MouseDragElementBehaviour` is simplistically applying a render transform to affect the movement.  However the ListView places its item panel inside a ScrollViewer which clips its content to its viewport.

Comment: I am aware of the Toolkit but wanted to finish it the "manual" way since I've put some effort in it now. Is there any quick workaround without using the Toolkit? If not, I'll mark your answer correct! Many thanks Anthony!

Comment: @David: I can't think of a "quick" workaround.  You would need to create a clone of the `ListBoxItem`, add it to the containing `Grid`, set its initial transform so that it covers the original list box item and then drag it about.  Whatever solution you use, it will be very different to what you have so far.